# save files on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a website for the project on of my course.this is a system with a lot of user and **each user can upload files on server**.  now i have two way for implementation that:

1. create a folder with name files and upload files in that and retrieve from that.
2. each user have a distinct folder and upload files in that.

the implementation of second way is easy but i think create a lot of folder(each user have distinct folder) may decrease the speed when every one try to load them from sever.

whats your opinion?
what way is better?

Comment: It will **not** affect performance, choose what you like the most.

Comment: Yeah! as gdoron said both will use equal amount of memory/cpu.

Comment: Web Forms or MVC? And how many users are you potentially targeting?

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to have a single folder called `uploads`.

Everytime a user uploads a file, generate a GUID, and assign this GUID as the filename. This will ensure that filenames will never collide.

After saving the file, store the following in a database: the original filename given by the user, the GUID name of the file and userid.

You can now retrieve files uploaded by any user by first looking up the GUID from the DB and then fetching the file from the filesystem.

You can generate GUIDs using the [`Guid.NewGuid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, save the association of `File` and `User` in the database using foreign keys. For example:

```
File
--------
FileId int
UserId (FK) int
PathToFile nvarchar
```

You then just save the *path* to the file to the table and keep the actual file in the computers filesystem.

Then in your application you can retrieve a list of files for `User Foo` and serve them up easily.

The process varies between ASP.Net Webforms and ASP.Net MVC. Which are you using?

Comment: -1 It was no where mentioned about storing files in database.

Comment: @Madcoder: I edited my answer to be clearer. I didn't mean 'save the file to the database.'

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any major issues with choice #2.  Be aware that [enumerating collections of files and directories will give you better performance than arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370.aspx).  Appending a guid to the file name will keep the file names unique.  You can remove that guid from the filename when serving the file as a download to the user.